# Parse JSON data from result with C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing

When I try to get the Json data from the response it does not work.
I'm new to Json so I'm not sure how to go about this.

Here is the code I have atm:

```
//process ajax and make API call to active campaign
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessPreferences(string categoryTag, string userEmailAddr)
    { 
        string applyToTag = categoryTag;
        string emailAddr = userEmailAddr;

        /*
         *   Active Campign API Integration
         */
        // By default, this sample code is designed to get the result from your ActiveCampaign installation and print out the result
        var acs = new Acs("api_key_removed", "api_url_removed");

        Dictionary<string, string> getParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        getParameters.Add("api_action", "contact_view_email");
        getParameters.Add("api_output", "json");
        getParameters.Add("email", emailAddr);

        var response = acs.SendRequest("GET", getParameters);
        var obj = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(response);

        return Content(obj.tags);
    }
}
```

Everything I find on google is not working.
I tried this but it not work:

```
var obj = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(response);
return Content(obj.tags);
```

I'm working with active campaign so might be a different method of getting json result, not sure.

Here is the data I want from the Json result.
[image]

I know the api call is working as I can write the Json data to browser console. `return Content(response);` Then written with jquery.

Comment: why not `return Content(response, "application/json");`

Comment: @lomed not sure, I'm new to working with JSON. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has already been answered, but I think in a cumbersome way.

There is no point in converting the respnse to an object just for return it back to the same state (JSON).

you need return the reponse as it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessPreferences(string categoryTag, string userEmailAddr)
{
    ...

    var response = acs.SendRequest("GET", getParameters);

    return Content(response, "application/json");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ActionResult go for JsonResult.
Try the below code:

```
public JsonResult ActionName()  
{  
    your code goes here ....
    return Json(outputobj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) How would I get the data i.e `return Content(obj.tags["0"]);` Currently i get red squiggly line under tags

Comment: You cannot return tags if it is not defined in C#, instead return the 'obj' and  iterate on front end.

Comment: Oh I see so I should do like this `.done(function (msg) {
            for (i in obj.tags) {
                //code here
            }
        })` on front end. Awesome thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest way to achieve your requirement. You are welcome :)